# Mapbox inaccurate results using unproject in mobile browser

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am having an issue in determining the lat/lng bounds of the visible viewport, after a lot of digging I thought I had this working by getting the canvas size and using unproject, this works fine for desktop testing. As an example this shows a simple map and draws a polygon the size of the visible area, if you zoom out a little you should see it.

```
  var displayBoundingBox = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(sw, ne);

  displayBoundingBox._ne.lat = map.unproject([map.getCanvas().width, 0]).lat;
  displayBoundingBox._ne.lng = map.unproject([map.getCanvas().width, 0]).lng;
  displayBoundingBox._sw.lat = map.unproject([0, map.getCanvas().height]).lat;
  displayBoundingBox._sw.lng = map.unproject([0, map.getCanvas().height]).lng;
```

https://jsbin.com/kesezamiya/2

If you visit the same link on a mobile browser (such as iOS Chrome or Safari) the polygon appears to be roughly 3-4 times the size of the visible map. I'm not sure if this is somehow related to retina displays or something but do not seem to be able to find anywhere this has been reported, I had assumed that identifying the visible area would be a pretty common ask.

Any suggestions would be most welcome, particularly whether this is an issue with unproject or with the canvas dimensions.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to track the visible area in order to refresh data as the map moves (while driving). I found that that the map bounds represented an area larger than the visible area, after a lot of searching it turns out I needed to unproject the canvas to get the lat/lng of the corners.

With this working on my desktop I tested on iOS and it all went weird, the canvas did not unproject the same way, after more digging it turns out this is related to (I think) retina style displays, this can be determined using window.devicePixelRatio, as such changing my code as shown below results in the correct viewport being identified on all devices. i.e. The returned canvas size on a retina device is 3x what would be expected.

```
displayBoundingBox._ne.lat = map.unproject([map.getCanvas().width / window.devicePixelRatio, 0]).lat;
displayBoundingBox._ne.lng = map.unproject([map.getCanvas().width / window.devicePixelRatio, 0]).lng;
displayBoundingBox._sw.lat = map.unproject([0, map.getCanvas().height / window.devicePixelRatio]).lat;
displayBoundingBox._sw.lng = map.unproject([0, map.getCanvas().height / window.devicePixelRatio]).lng;
```